# Check for a users command while executing a command

Tags: python, discord.py

How do you do it, that if someone uses a command, a timer starts and does something if a user answers in a in the given time?
Like someone does "!shoot @user#0000" and the tagged user has to answer with "!dodge" in under 10 seconds or he dies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `wait_for` [method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for):

```py
@client.command(name = "shoot")
async def shoot_user(ctx, user: discord.Member):
   channel = ctx.channel
   def check(m):
        return m.content == '!dodge' and m.channel == channel and m.author == user
   try:
        await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout = 10.0)     
   except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await channel.send(f"{user.mention} did not dodge in time!")
   else:
        await channel.send(f"{user.mention} dodged!")
```